# ODOO 10 related field not updated

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

This related field working fine in `odoo 9`, but not in `odoo 10`. The field `customer_id` not updated when I create a new record with `nomor_hp_id`.

```py
nomor_hp_id = fields.Many2one(
    string='Nomor hp',
    comodel_name='nomor.hp',
    ondelete='cascade',
)
customer_id = fields.Many2one(
    string='Customer',
    related='nomor_hp_id.customer_id',
    ondelete='cascade',
    store=True,
    readonly=True,
)
```

Try to start new database but the result still not updated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give comodel name inside `Many2one` field either it is normal `Many2one` or related `Many2one`. Please have a look at below code. You will get your answer.

```py
nomor_hp_id = fields.Many2one(string='Nomor hp', comodel_name='nomor.hp',ondelete='cascade',)

customer_id = fields.Many2one(string='Customer', comodel_name='res.partner', related='nomor_hp_id.customer_id', ondelete='cascade',readonly=True,)
```

You have to define the reference of which table. Here `customer_id` is the reference field of the "`res_partner`" table or "`res.partner`" model.

Answer (score 0):

This way works fine for me.

```py
customer_id = fields.Many2one(
    string='Customer',
    related='nomor_hp_id.customer_id',
    store=True,
)
```